# Command to run boot service program from background (through command line)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class IFMApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IFMApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(IFMApp.class);
    }
}
```

I want to run above boot service program (IFMApp) through the command line (linux terminal).

The War/Jar files i built:-

**1.** ifmservice.war

**2.** ifmservice-jar-with-dependencies.jar

**3.** ifmservice-tests.jar

Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to run it using `java -jar ifmservice-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ,go to  your target folder in your  project  and then  type in :

java -jar  your_jar_Name